# Connecting a wrapper class to another class

Tags: java

So I have this wrapper program that enables me to return two quantities from a method.

** Wrapper Class**

```
public class Words 
{

    private String leftWords;
    private String rightWords;

    public Words(String leftWords, String rightWords) {
        this.leftWords = leftWords;
        this.rightWords = rightWords;
    }

    public String getLeftWords() {
        return leftWords;
    }

    public String getRightWords() {
        return rightWords;
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((leftWords == null) ? 0 : leftWords.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((rightWords == null) ? 0 : rightWords.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Words other = (Words) obj;
        if (leftWords == null)
        {
            if (other.leftWords != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!leftWords.equals(other.leftWords))
            return false;
        if (rightWords == null)
        {
            if (other.rightWords != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!rightWords.equals(other.rightWords))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

The method I want to tie this with is :

```
private static Map <Set<String>,Set<Words>> getLeftRightWords(LinkedHashMap<Set<String>,Set<Integer>> nnpIndexTokens, NLChunk chunk) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
    //  Map <Set<String>,Set<Integer>> nnpMap = new LinkedHashMap<Set<String>, Set<Integer>>();
        Map <Set<String>,Set<Words>> contextMap = new LinkedHashMap<Set<String>, Set<Words>>(); 
        Set<Words> leftRightWords = new HashSet<Words>();


        //for(NLChunk chunk : sentence.getChunks()){

        if(chunk.getStrPostags().contains("NNP")){


            String leftWords = "";
            String rightWords = "";

            int chunkStartIndex =  chunk.getStartIndex();
            int chunkEndIndex = chunk.getEndIndex();

            //nnpMap = getNNPs(chunk);


            String previous = null;
            int previousNnpEndIndex = 0;
            int previousNnpStartIndex = 0;


            for (Map.Entry<Set<String>, Set<Integer>> entry : nnpIndexTokens.entrySet()){


                for (Iterator<String> i = entry.getKey().iterator(); i.hasNext();){
                    Set<Integer> entryIndex = null;
                    int nnpStartIndex = 0;
                    int nnpEndIndex = 0;

                    String currentElement = i.next();


                    //Deriving values for beginning and ending of chunk 
                    //and beginning and ending of NNP

                    if (!(entry.getValue().isEmpty())){

                        if (currentElement.trim().split(" ").length > 1){
                             entryIndex = entry.getValue();
                             nnpStartIndex = entryIndex.iterator().next();
                             nnpEndIndex = getLastElement(entryIndex); 

                        }

                        else {
                             entryIndex = entry.getValue();
                             nnpStartIndex = entryIndex.iterator().next();
                             nnpEndIndex = nnpStartIndex;
                        }   

                    }   

                    if(!(chunkStartIndex<=nnpStartIndex && chunkEndIndex>=nnpEndIndex)){
                        continue;
                    }
                        //Extracting LEFT WORDS of the NNP

                    //1)If another NNP is present in left words, left words of current NNP start from end index of previous NNP
                        if (previous != null && chunk.toString().substring(chunkStartIndex, nnpStartIndex).contains(previous)){

                            int leftWordsEndIndex =  nnpStartIndex;
                            int leftWordsStartIndex = previousNnpEndIndex;


                            for (NLWord nlword : chunk.getTokens())
                            {
                                if(nlword.getIndex()>=leftWordsStartIndex  
                                        && nlword.getIndex()<leftWordsEndIndex )
                                leftWords+=nlword.getToken()  +" ";


                            }

                            System.out.println("LEFT WORDS:" + leftWords+ "OF:"+ currentElement);

                        }

                    //2) If no left words are present       

                        if (chunkStartIndex == nnpStartIndex){
                            System.out.println("NO LEFT WORDS");

                        }
                        //3) Normal case where left words consist of all the words left of the NNP starting from the beginning of the chunk
                        else {


                            for (NLWord nlword : chunk.getTokens())
                            {
                                if(nlword.getIndex()>=chunkStartIndex  
                                        && nlword.getIndex()<nnpStartIndex )
                                leftWords+=nlword.getToken()  +" ";


                            }

                            System.out.println("LEFT WORDS:" + leftWords+ "OF:"+ currentElement);
                        }


                        //Extracting RIGHT WORDS of NNP
                     if (entry.getKey().iterator().hasNext()){// entry.getKey().iterator().hasNext()){

                            String  nextElement = entry.getKey().iterator().next();

                            //1)If another NNP is present in right words, right words of current NNP start from end index of current NNP to beginning of next NNP
                         if (nextElement !=null && nextElement != currentElement && chunk.toString().substring(entry.getValue().iterator().next(), chunkEndIndex).contains(nextElement)){

                                int rightWordsStartIndex = entryIndex.iterator().next();
                                int rightWordsEndIndex = entry.getValue().iterator().next();


                                //String rightWord="";

                                for (NLWord nlword : chunk.getTokens())
                                {
                                    if(nlword.getIndex()>=rightWordsStartIndex  
                                            && nlword.getIndex()<rightWordsEndIndex )
                                    rightWords+=nlword.getToken()  +" ";


                                }

                                System.out.println("LEFT WORDS:" + leftWords+ "OF:"+ currentElement);
                            }
                        }

                            //2) If no right words exist
                        if(nnpEndIndex == chunkEndIndex){
                                System.out.println("NO RIGHT WORDS");
                                //continue;
                            }

                            //3) Normal case where right words consist of all the words right of the NNP starting from the end of the NNP till the end of the chunk
                        else {

                                for (NLWord nlword : chunk.getTokens())
                                {
                                    if(nlword.getIndex()>=nnpEndIndex+1  
                                            && nlword.getIndex()<=chunkEndIndex )
                                        rightWords+=nlword.getToken()  +" ";


                                }

                                System.out.println("RIGHT WORDS:" + rightWords+ "OF:"+ currentElement);
                            }



                    if (previous == null){
                        previous = currentElement;
                        previousNnpStartIndex = nnpStartIndex;
                        previousNnpEndIndex = nnpEndIndex;
                    }

                    Words contextWords = new Words(leftWords.toString(), rightWords.toString());
                    leftRightWords.add(contextWords);


                }
                contextMap.put(entry.getKey(), leftRightWords);
            }//nnps set

        }

        System.out.println(contextMap);
        return contextMap;  
    }
```

As you can see what I am trying to do in this method is taking a proper noun and extracting the left and right words of that proper noun.E.g for a chunk **"fellow Rhode Island solution provider"** my output is:

> LEFT WORDS:fellow OF:Rhode Island
>   RIGHT WORDS:solution provider OF:Rhode Island

Now I want to put these in a map where Rhode Island is the key and the values for this are solution provider and fellow.

When I try to print this map the output  get is:

> {[Rhode Island ]=[com.gyan.siapp.nlp.test.Words@681330f0]}

How do i get the right output?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using a `Set` as a key.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `Set` as a value and `String`, not a `Set<String>` for storing `leftWords` and `rightWords`.

Comment: I was using Set<String> earlier but changed it. I can revert back if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the only issue but your class `Words` does not override
`toString()` method.

Not sure about your Java skill level. So sorry if im posting what you are familiar to. 
`System.out.println(...)` calls `toString()` method to get message for the object.
By overriding default with your own implementation

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "leftWords: "+leftWords+", rightWords: "+rightWords;
}
```

You change `com.gyan.siapp.nlp.test.Words@681330f0` to your own output.

Comment: @Thomas F.  Thanks for the answer. I would call myself a beginner in java. So what you are saying is that I need to comment out the override from the wrapper?

Comment: No, you need to copy my code to the wrapper. And it seems to me that you do not properly understand `Map` semantics, check some help for that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? The reason I stopped using set for left and right words is because I need to match these left and right words against a few lists of words to classify the proper noun into name, place or organization. With a set as a data structure I later need to convert it into string format for matching. hence decided to use string from the get go. Will this cause an issue?

Comment: Well, First
Map<Set<Whatever>, Whatever> is something you do not see every day, so it smells us (Klitos and me) Maybe it is correct but the code is too long and contains too much unknown dependencies, so I really dont know. Take it just as a smell, something to check.
Secondly
You return a map with at most one key-value pair in it, am I right? (I judge because you put `leftRightWords` object inside and this is created only once)
 I advised you to check it because map is not intended for that.